# NodeJS with mysql returning the first query result

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have  a NodeJS with Express and mysql. I have put an Generic sql function so I call it for multiple times:

```
exports.selectCommand=function(table,cols,cond){
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : hostname,
        database: databasename,
        user     : username
    });
    try{
        connection.query("SELECT "+cols+" As data from "+table+" where "+cond+" ", function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) return "sorry, an error accoured. Please try again later";
            if(rows.length!=0){
            cmd = rows[0].data.toString();
            }
        });
    }catch (e){console.log(e.message);}
    connection.end();
    return cmd; };
```

I send the query thorugh it but the problem it return the first query I send it.

I've put the above function in another file and I call it:

```
var db=require('./db.js');
..........
exports.psModel=function(){
    var cmddata="";
    cmddata=db.selectCommand("cmd","value","cmd='textbox'");
}
```

Comment: For some reason the var is not chainging it's value @amrswalha

Comment: what mysql package for node are you using first ?

Answer (score 2):

your `return cmd` returns probably before the query is processed. The call is asynchronous. Try to place the return statement within the callback (and the connection end as well). Something like this:

```
try{
    connection.query("SELECT "+cols+" As data from "+table+" where "+cond+" ",
        function(err, rows, fields) {
            connection.end();
            if (err) return "sorry, an error occurred. Please try again later";
            if(rows.length!=0){
              cmd = rows[0].data.toString();
              return cmd;
            }
        });
    }catch (e){console.log(e.message);}
```

Comment: the cmd if it's inside the callback it return null value @luksch

Comment: can you log to the console how your SQL query looks like? also, log the result row to the console

Comment: SELECT value As data from cmd where cmd='textbox'

Comment: And what does the ```SELECT value As data from cmd where cmd='textbox'; ``` return when you do it directly within the mysql console?

Comment: It return result but the value of the cmd does not change for some reason

Comment: it is confusing that you seem to have a table named ```'cmd'``` and also a column of that table named ```'cmd'``` and finally you name the data column of the first result row also ```'cmd'```...